# References on mathematically rigorous general equilibrium theories

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-economics, general-equilibrium

I'm looking for a relatively recent survey on the state of the art for mathematical general equilibrium. I'm especially interested in questions of uniqueness, stability and dynamics. (I'm planing on giving a talk on general equilibrium at the level of Jehle and Reny to some mathematicians who have no economics background, and I'd like to be as up to date as possible.)

Comment: You might want to look over the development of GE in [Kreps](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691155836/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_LW9Byb52WYXEJ).

Comment: I am not a theorist, but as far as I can tell the state of the art on these questions is quite old and there's no active research going on. The classic comprehensive reference for GE theory is Mas-Colell, Whinston and Greene's Microeconomic Theory textbook, Kreps is a newer textbook but I don't think it adds a lot.

Comment: Probably not complete enough for your purpose but this may help: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11784-009-0129-2